# How to make a java program with output a triangle of numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I understand that there is a similar post to this one, but based on the answers I can not both apply the answers to my current class, or understand the rest of the answers.

I need to create a program using nested "for loops" that creates an output like this one (just symmetrical).  I have been trying to get this to work for two whole evenings now, and can't figure it out...

```
               1 
             1 2 1 
            1 2 4 2 1 
          1 2 4 8 4 2 1 
        1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1 
      1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1 
   1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

I would GREATLY appreciate any help!!!

```
public class PyramidOfDoom { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        int k = 2; 
        int totalWidth = 8; 
        for (int row = 1; row <= totalWidth; row++) { 
            for (int col = 1; col <= totalWidth; col++) { 
                if (col <= totalWidth - row) { 
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.print(k);; 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working for you? Surely after working on it for *two* whole evenings, you can post some sort of effort.

Comment: It's not letting me copy and paste my code into the comment section for some reason...give me a second.

Comment: Ermm..so sorry about this.  Does anyone know how to get my code on here?  I try to type it in, hit enter, and it just submits my comment...ugh, struggling tonight!

Comment: There we go!  Got my current code uploaded.  It has the output of half of the triangle, just all 2's!

Comment: @BenToms Remember if you are struggling with a programming problem, the best thing to do is *solve a simpler problem first*. For example, for this particular problem I would suggest you start by writing a function that will produce a string with all the powers of 2 up to `2^n`, then modify it to produce a string up to `2^n` and back down to `1`. Once you have that down, you can repeat that in a loop to generate your pyramid, and once you have **that** down you can worry about centering the output.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it can be done in simple steps as 1. print leading spaces 2. print increasing numbers 3. print decreasing number 4. print trailing spaces 5 print new line.

Sample code(concept) as below.

```
    int row = 10;
    for(int i=1; i<=numRow ; i++){
       int num = 1;
       for(int j=0; j<numRow- i; j++ ){
           System.out.print("   ");
       }
       for(int j=numRow-i+1; j<=numRow ; j++ ){
           System.out.print(num+" ");
           num=num*2;
       }
       num=num/2;
       for(int j=numRow+1; j<numRow+i; j++ ){
           num=num/2;
           System.out.print(num+" ");
       }
       for(int j=numRow+i+1; j<=numRow*2; j++ ){
           System.out.print("  ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: I've only been programming for 7 weeks now, and just got taught for loops so I'm still trying to learn this.  Thanks so much for the help, I'll look this code over, adjust it for my problem and repost!

Comment: I posted a sample code from learning aspect only. If you notice, I am first printing the blanks, then increasing numbers up to the middle, then decreasing number to the middle followed by space. Once one line is completed, added a new line statement. All this I did for your concept learning otherwise we could write more compact and fancy code. Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped very much, I re-wrote your code (to teach myself) and adjusted it to fit what I needed.  I'm not adjusting it for neatness!  Thanks SO much!

Comment: Good to know that your were able to follow the concept and make it working. It worked for you, please accept the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing `k` at all.  You need to keep multiplying it by 2 until you get to the middle of the row, then start dividing it by 2.  As it stands, in your `System.out.println(k)`, how can you expect it to print anything but 2 if you never manipulate it? :)

Also, you have two semicolons in your `System.out.println(k);;`.  That seems odd to me, but I suppose it actually makes sense that it would compile.

Comment: `System.out.println(k);;` is actually two statements: `System.out.println(k);` and `;`. `;` is an empty statement, and is perfectly legal syntactically in Java and many other languages, but mostly useless. You could end every line with `;;;;;` if you wanted, but I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jeff.  This explanation helped extensively...I was getting so caught in trying to use exponents that I didn't try to just use * /.  That extra ; was just hanging there from accidentally not deleting an entire line of useless code.